# Radial motions moment of inertia

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm looking for some references on a specific moment of inertia, for ***radial motions*** of a *spherical body*.  In my calculations, I got this integral :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\bar{I} = \int r^2 \, dm = \int_{\mathcal{V}} \rho(r) \, r^2 \, d^3 x,
\end{equation}
where $\rho$ is the matter density and $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ defines the usual radial coordinate (the coordinates origin is located at the center of the spherical body).  For an uniform mass distribution, this integral is easy to do :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\bar{I} = \frac{3}{5} \; M R^2.
\end{equation}
Please, don't confuse this with the well known moment of inertia of the sphere, around some *rotation* axis.  This is about ***radial*** motions, and not rotation.

I never saw this in any books on mechanics.

Notice that expression (1) above is also half the *trace* of the inertia tensor :
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
I_{ij} = \int_{\mathcal{V}} (r^2 \, \delta_{ij} - x_i \, x_j) \, \rho \; d^3 x,
\end{equation}
Then we have this :
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\bar{I} \equiv \frac{1}{2} \; I_{kk}.
\end{equation}

I'm not sure the "radial inertia moment" defined by (1) (if it have a proper interpretation) is getting the proper factor.

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Isn't “radial motion” just a plain center of mass motion and the “moment of inertia” is just the mass $M$ of that sphere?

Comment: @MartinUeding, I'm not sure.  Imagine an uniform sphere at the center of your origin system.  Give it some radial motion (compression, dilatation, oscillations), without breaking the spherical symetry.  I think that integral (1) measures its inertia for such radial motions.

Comment: What physical significance do you think that the physical quantity in eqns (1) or (2) has? Can you write an equation which uses it? eg Something similar to $L = I\omega$ relating angular momentum and angular velocity. Or perhaps this is the question which you are asking us to answer? Just because you can write a mathematical definition does not mean that it has any physical significance.

Comment: @sammygerbil, it's related to energy and radial oscillations of the sphere : \begin{equation} \bar{I} \; \frac{d^2 \delta R}{d t^2} = (3 \gamma - 4) \, U \, \delta R,\end{equation} where $\gamma$ is the adiabatic index of the material and $U$ is the potential energy of the sphere.  $\bar{I}$ is the "radial moment of inertia" I defined above. $R$ is the radius of the whole sphere, and $\delta R = R - R_0$ is its variation (relative to the equilibrium value $R_0$) changing in time because of gravity and internal pressure.

Comment: What do you mean by radial motion? Translation and rotation completely describe one object's motion unless  you're examining object deformation which is a whole bag of worms. If we have a second object, their motions may be described, for example, by the relative motion of the bodies, their rotations, and the movement of the system. How many bodies, and which way might they be moving?

Comment: @user121330, radial motions of a sphere !  Just imagine a pulsating sphere (expanding and/or contracting).

Comment: I think a little more context could be useful. You mean a uniformly pulsating sphere, as in a pulsating star (not a rigid body), right? In this case, the velocity of a point is $v_i=\dot\epsilon x_i$, and the kinetic energy in a volume $dV$ is $\rho v^2 dV/2$ where $d\bar I=\rho v^2 dV$ is your "pulsatile moment of inertia" of element, where $v^2=\dot\epsilon^2 x_i^2$. If you want to compare this to rotations, remember that $\vec v=\vec\omega\times\vec r$, and you can expand this as $\rho v^2 dV=I_{ij}x_i x_j$. The derivations are similar; you might expect some relation between $\bar I$ and I.

Comment: @exmachina, your calculation appears to be similar to mine.  So you get the same equation as the one in my comment above ?  This pulsating sphere should be exposed somewhere.  Any references for this ?

Comment: So you're looking at an object that's deforming... What are you trying to determine - the motion of a particle in a medium? The volume (/radius/surface area) of the sphere as a function of time?

Comment: @user121330, the radius of the sphere as a function of time.  I already have the differential equation (given in a message above).  I was simply wondering about this "radial moment of inertia".

Comment: @Cham An adequate google search should get you something. See for instance eqn. (6) in p. 139 here: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1954AJ.....59..137H where the author gives the $\frac 35 MR^2$ expression for a spherical body. This being related to the trace of the rotational inertia matrix is due to the fact that both are related to squares/products of coordinates and $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ is the only scalar combination of those. However I and $\bar I$ have very different physical meanings.

Comment: @exmachina, then this is precisely the sense of my question !  What is the physical meaning of $\bar{I}$ ? (which I called the "radial moment of inertia, since it's related to the ***trace*** of the inertia tensor).

Comment: @exmachina, take note that equation (13) in the paper your referenced is similar (but not identical) to the equation in my second message above.  My equation is more general since it's about a *polytropic* spherical cloud of gaz (i.e. a star) of adiabatic index $\gamma$.  My equation shows that a star made of relativistic gas ; $\gamma = \frac{4}{3}$, is unstable.  If $\gamma < \frac{4}{3}$, the star will implode or explode (since $U < 0$).

Comment: How can there be a moment of inertia without any rotation? No rotation => No angular momentum => No MMOI. You need to provide more context in the question or add some links where this $I$ is used.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is half the trace. Given the three principal components on some coordinate system are
$$ \begin{align}
   I_{xx} & = \int (y^2+z^2) {\rm d}m \\
   I_{yy} & = \int (z^2+x^2) {\rm d}m \\
   I_{zz} & = \int (x^2+y^2) {\rm d}m 
\end{align} $$

Add them up to get

$$ I_{xx}+ I_{yy}+I_{zz} = \int (2 x^2+2 y^2+2 z^2) {\rm d}m  $$

which is double the value in your definition of

$$ I_{radial} = \int ( x^2+y^2+ z^2) {\rm d}m  $$

**The bigger question here is, how is the above derived and how is it used**? I think the *OP* needs to provide more details for the question to be answered effectively.

Comment: I found the "radial moment of inertia" $\bar{I}$ by writing down the differential equation of a **radially pulsating star**.  The quantity $\bar{I}$ entered my equation as an inertia factor in front of a second time derivative (from Newton's equation), so I was wondering about its proper physical meaning.

Comment: If there is a physical meaning, then it is not MMOI or something related to it.

Comment: MMOI ?  What is that ?

Comment: @Cham - Sorry, Mass Moment of Inertia (MMOI)

Answer (score 0):

The moment of inertia is the measure of resistance to angular acceleration about an axis.  Unless I'm mistaken, what you're after is the modulus of elasticity $E$ (or Poisson's ratio $\nu$) of the object.  That dictates the response to radial motion given a uniform pressure field acting on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: Take note that the integral I defined for radial motions is the trace of the inertia tensor for any rotation.  Is the elasticity modulus related to the inertia tensor ?

Comment: No, it's not related to the inertia tensor, but neither is radial motion.  The modulus of elasticity is a material property, and it is defined as the ratio of stress to strain for a given material.  You simply cannot quantify the resistance to axial (or radial) strain using a moment of inertia tensor.

Comment: Why not ?  In my calculations, I got that radial integral (which is the trace of the inertia tensor, by some coincidence).  So I strongly think that integral has something to say about radial motion "resistence" (i.e. inertia).